# Google places api's in android

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

**Android Google Places APIs**,

How can I show *Google Places* and my particular places from server side in an Android map view.

Comment: now i will try google places show on map view and whatever i will add some new places that also show in map view. like a justdial app

Answer (score -2, accepted):

please find this link where you need to create your api key and you to use that key in your project https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/

Comment: This answer has severe formatting or content problems. This answer is unlikely to be salvageable through editing, and might need to be removed.

Comment: i have already done google places but i have some more places(using latitude& longitude) so how show that same map view those all places....??

Comment: pass your lat & long for near by categories for the map view.